# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent

Tags: android

I implemented reverse geocoding inside GCMIntentService onMessage method. I got exception **java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=com.android.location.service.GeocodeProvider pkg=com.google.android.location }**
after application running long time. If i restart device it works again fine. Also i seen android open isssue **[Reconnection with Geocoder services not possible when Network Location Service is killed.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39635)**. Is it any work around to solve this issue?

Note : I am running Application in Samsung galaxy Tab 2(Android 4.1.1)

Comment: any answer will be appreciated

Comment: I checked [the other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22not+allowed+to+bind+to+service+intent%22) about this exception text but they didn't help me. If you did the same, in my case the problem was that two apps was using my library that provided the service. The system always allowed the first activity to bind and all forthcoming attempts to bind an activity resulted in this exception. I uninstalled all other users of the library since all were my test apps and this solved it for me. It's maybe not a suitable "solution" for you but may get you in the right direction if no else.

Comment: found any solutions?

Comment: facing same issue. :( @Ramprasad found any workaround?